# Can't launch Fragment from RecyclerView adapter

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, nullpointerexception

There is a code for the NameListHolder class located in the RecyclerView adapter

```
class NameListHolder(val binding: NameListItemBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

    fun bind(paginationLocalModel: PaginationLocalModel, position: Int, context: NameListFragment){

        binding.name.text = paginationLocalModel.name
        itemView.setOnClickListener{

            val fragment = DescriptionFragment()
            val bundle = Bundle()
            bundle.putInt("position", position)
            fragment.setArguments(bundle)

            val activity=context.context as AppCompatActivity
            activity.supportFragmentManager
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.rd_fragment, fragment)
                .commitNow()

            Log.d("OnClick", "произошло нажатие по позиции $position")
        }

    }

}
```

Inside `itemView.setOnClickListener` the fragment should fire, but when I click on the list item, a `NullPointerException` is thrown:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.sem.receivedata, PID: 5484
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.sem.receivedata.presentation.DescriptionFragment.<init>(DescriptionFragment.kt:22)
        at com.sem.receivedata.presentation.adapters.NameListAdapter$NameListHolder.bind$lambda-0(NameListAdapter.kt:49)
        at com.sem.receivedata.presentation.adapters.NameListAdapter$NameListHolder.$r8$lambda$FuXGFWDKhm2ZD3YhtF7Xh98aUvc(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.sem.receivedata.presentation.adapters.NameListAdapter$NameListHolder$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onClick(Unknown Source:4)
```

`DescriptionFragment.kt:22` points to the string `val position: Int = bundle!!.getInt("position", 0)` inside the `DescriptionFragment` fragment

`NameListAdapter.kt:49` points to the line `val fragment = DescriptionFragment()` inside the `NameListHolder`

`Unknown Source:0` and `Unknown Source:4` always point to line 0 and 4, no matter what is there (before there were `newInstance()` imports)

The whole data chain:

`NameListFragment`:

```
class NameListFragment : Fragment() {

...

    private fun initRecyclerExchangeRate(){
    
        binding?.listNameRV?.layoutManager =
            LinearLayoutManager(context)
        nameListAdapter = NameListAdapter(this)
    
        binding?.listNameRV?.adapter = nameListAdapter
    }

...

}
```

`NameListAdapter`:

```
class NameListAdapter(var context: NameListFragment
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<NameListAdapter.NameListHolder>() {

...

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: NameListHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(pagination[position], position, context)
    }

...


    class NameListHolder(val binding: NameListItemBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
    
        fun bind(paginationLocalModel: PaginationLocalModel, position: Int, context: NameListFragment){
    
            binding.name.text = paginationLocalModel.name
            itemView.setOnClickListener{
    
                val fragment = DescriptionFragment()
                val bundle = Bundle()
                bundle.putInt("position", position)
                fragment.setArguments(bundle)
    
                val activity=context.context as AppCompatActivity
                activity.supportFragmentManager
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.rd_fragment, fragment)
                    .commitNow()
    
                Log.d("OnClick", "произошло нажатие по позиции $position")
            }
    
        }
    
    }

...

}
```

`DescriptionFragment`:

```
class DescriptionFragment : Fragment() {

...

    val bundle: Bundle? = this.getArguments();
    val position: Int = bundle!!.getInt("position", 0)

...

}
```

The launch of the first fragment from the Activity is done inside the markup:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".presentation.MainActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/framelayout"
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/rd_fragment"
                android:name="com.sem.receivedata.presentation.NameListFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />



        </FrameLayout>

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are creating new fragment in this line

```
val fragment = DescriptionFragment()
```

so it gets created and at start it tries to parse bundle

```
val bundle: Bundle? = this.getArguments();
val position: Int = bundle!!.getInt("position", 0)
```

which isn't set yet, you are doing this in next lines after `Fragment` creation. but you are forcing to read from bundle (`!!`) at very beginning, it's `null` at this moment, so `NullPointerException` occurs

your aproach is just wrong, you should read arguments in some lifecycle method like `onCreate` or `onCreateView`, when you are shure that `Fragment` is created, is set up (e.g. `Bundle` arguments set), is added to layout and running (as it is calling lifecycle methods)